# Communicate between two applications without MSMQ

Tags: windows, msmq

How can I send and retrieve messages in Windows without the MSMQ feature?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ah, THAT's what they meant...

Comment: But my question is " how multiple receivers access(send and receive) serverside msmq without create queue itself?

Comment: How would that be possible? That's like sending a letter to a house which doesn't exist. You can write whatever address you like on the envelope and the post office will accept it but the address has to be meaningful. Could you describe what you are actually trying to do and why? Context may help.

Comment: The original question was confusing as MSMQ is a Windows feature so "without the MSMQ feature" means "without MSMQ installed".

Comment: Is there any possible for create centralized queue(in server side).and it will be used by all other systems?

Comment: Sure, that's normal. Any system running an MSMQ client can remotely access a queue hosted on any other MSMQ machine (to send messages to or receive messages from).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response bro.

Answer (score 0):

MSMQ is a network protocol so as long as you can write the data onto the wire in the right format, you'd be able to avoid installing MSMQ but normally you would make use of the installed MSMQ feature to handle all the messaging, handshaking, storage, etc.

In theory you could write your own queue manager application to replace what Windows installs for the MSMQ feature. For example, you may want to do that on a non-Windows platform.

As writing your own queue manager is a significant development project, most people don't bother and instead use what's there already.